# default parameter and out parameter in C# in same method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

**I tried to create a calculator program but in division method i need 2 values to be return they are remainder in default parameter and quotient in out parameter i tried my best of research but i cant get the answer correctly**

```
using System;
public class Calculator
{
public int Addition(int a, int b){
int sum = a+b;
return sum;
}
public int Subtraction(int a, int b){
int diff = a-b;
return diff;
}
public int Multiplication(int a, int b){
int mul = a*b;
return mul;
}
public double Division(int a, int b, out double remainder){
double div = a/b;
double rem = a%b;
remainder = rem;
return div;
}
}
public class program{
public static void Main(){
Calculator c  = new Calculator();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
char s=Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter the operands");
int a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int b=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
switch(s)
{
case '+':
int summ = c.Addition(a,b);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} + {1} is {2}",a,b,summ);
break;
case '-':
int sub = c.Subtraction(a,b);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} - {1} is {2}",a,b,sub);
break;
case'*':
int mul = c.Multiplication(a,b);    
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} * {1} is {2}",a,b,mul);
break;
case '/':
double div = c.Division(a,b,out a);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} / {1} is {2} and rem is {3}",a,b,div,a);
break;
default:
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operand");
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just return an array with both values ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yda5c8dx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Consider using `int` rather than `double` in `Division`. There is no need to use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

double divisionReminder; //for your out parameter

Calculator c  = new Calculator();

double divResult = c.Division(33/8,divisionRemider);

divResult  will be 4

devisionRemider will be 1

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong here

`case '/':
    double div = c.Division(a,b,out a);
    Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} / {1} is {2} and rem is {3}",a,b,div,a);
    break;`

you have to declare new varible in main function to store reminder EX: int rem;

**the solution is:**

```
case '/':
int rem;
double div = c.Division(a,b,out rem);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} / {1} is {2} and rem is {3}",a,b,div,rem);
break;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
public class Calculator{
public int Addition(int a, int b){
int sum = a+b;
return sum;
}
public int Subtraction(int a, int b){
int diff = a-b;
return diff;
}
public int Multiplication(int a, int b){
int mul = a*b;
return mul;
}
public double Division(int a, int b, out double remainder){
double div = a/b;
double rem = a%b;
remainder = rem;
return div;
}
}

public class program{
public static void Main(){
double remainder;
Calculator c  = new Calculator();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
char s=Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter the operands");
int a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int b=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    
switch(s)
{
case '+':
int summ = c.Addition(a,b);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} + {1} is {2}",a,b,summ);
break;
case '-':
int sub = c.Subtraction(a,b);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} - {1} is {2}",a,b,sub);
break;
case'*':
int mul = c.Multiplication(a,b);    
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} * {1} is {2}",a,b,mul);
break;
case '/':
double div = c.Division(a,b,out remainder);
Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} / {1} is {2} and rem is {3}",a,b,div,remainder);
break;
default:
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operand");
break;
}
}
}
```